# Exceptions when working with big images

Tags: c#, image, memory, bitmap, overflow

I working on a maze generator in C# which generates big mazes and then saves them to a png file.

Currently I'm running against some errors when I'm trying to save the image.

When I use this:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap tempBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(16000, 16000);
```

I get an argument exception. (It does work with 8000*8000)

When I use the WPF way of doing it:

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = 
              new RenderTargetBitmap(16000, 16000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
```

I get a memory overflow exception.

Does anyone have another way to save big images in c#?

I've looked at some libraries too without success.

Someone also said that I should first save the image in parts and then combine them, but how can I do this?

### Edit:

Edit2:
I'm now trying PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed like this:

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage2(BitArray[] map, List<Point> path)
{
    Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(cursize * (map[0].Length - 1), cursize * (map.Length - 1), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, objBmpImage.Width, objBmpImage.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        objBmpImage.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        objBmpImage.PixelFormat);

    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * objBmpImage.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

    int counter = 0;
    int counterdeluxe = 0;
    BitArray bitarray = new BitArray(8);

    Random r = new Random();

    Boolean last = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 225 / 8; i++)
    {
        rgbValues[i] = (byte)r.Next(255);
    }

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);


    objBmpImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);

    return (objBmpImage);
}
```

Though for some reason it only creates half an image:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1814002/maze.png

Edit4:
Ah it seems that the bits in the width are always rounded up to a 4 byte number. Now it starts to make sense to me :).

Edit5:
Ok it doesn't make sense anymore lol, I'll just stay with the graphics for now I guess

Edit6:
I couldn't let it go so I looked at it again and found out the following:
At the point where I use a BitArray to convert my seperate bits to a byte which I then write to the ImageData something was going wrong, apparently the bitarray had to be written to in reverse. Finally everything works correctly now :).

All problems solved and my maze generator is up and running. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your mazes are just black/white, you might want to try:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(16000, 16000, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
```

Assuming it keeps the image in that format in memory, that should be considerably more efficient than the default pixel format.

On my box (which has 12GB of memory, admittedly), 16000x16000 works by default, but 32000x32000 doesn't. Even 32000x32000 works with `Format1bppIndexed` though.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you should use `using` statements for bitmaps:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = ...)
{
}
```

... so that they can be cleaned up appropriately.

Comment: Isn't a 16000x16000 32bpp bitmap roughly 1GB?  I always thought that it had nothing to do with your physical RAM and everything to do with the 32-bit Windows virtual address space (4GB total, but only 2GB accessible).

Comment: @Moozhe: I really wouldn't like to say for sure, to be honest. All manner of optimizations and strategies could be in play here, including it fitting in the *graphics card* memory...

Comment: Note: When you actually use this, you'll want to wrap it in a `using` block or call `Dispose` or you risk getting `OutOfMemory` exceptions.  E.g., see [Tess's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/02/03/net-memory-leak-to-dispose-or-not-to-dispose-that-s-the-1-gb-question.aspx)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: When I try PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed I get another exception in 
the line of code after it:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1814002/next.png

Comment: @user1149816: Okay, in that case you might want to try `Format16bppGrayScale`. Obviously that'll take much more in the way of resources, but it *might* work for you...

Comment: Or just don't use `Graphics`.  If your maze is grid-based, dealing with the array by hand is doable, though a hassle.

Comment: @Brian: I can't find information about doing that, could you help me a little?
Also, I would prefer colors in my maze to be able to show the path from start to end, but I guess there isn't a way to cope with bigger images?

Comment: Are you 32 bit or 64 bit?
Generally images use a single block of contiguous memory.  Getting 1 gig in 32 bit block of contiguous memory can be a challenge.

Comment: @user1149816: See for example [this page](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/13/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-i/).  The basic trick is to call [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) to get a [`BitmapData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx), which can then be accessed as a pointer to raw data (using either an `IntPtr` or a `byte*`, the latter of which tends to be much faster).

Comment: @TNT I'm using 64 bit
I will try what brian said :)

Comment: @user1149816: Are you *sure* you're using the 64-bit CLR? Being on 64-bit Windows isn't the same as the process *running* as a 64-bit process. Just something to check.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:
Thank you very much for telling me this, I can now generate mazes of up to 16000 * 16000, :)

Comment: @user1149816: Why are you only filling in the first 225/8 values? Why not use `rgbValues.Length`? Note that you probably want `rng.Next(256)` btw.

Comment: Well apparently every line has a rounded number to 4 bytes, so every line in the image actually has 32 bits (instead of 15) so that's why half of my image dissapeared.

Comment: @user1149816: That's where you should use the `Stride` and `Width` properties together.